# Restoring site collection to previous URL causes error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, restore

I can restore a site to a new URL, but if I try to restore to the URL I was previously using, I get:

```
Restore-SPSite <previousUrl> Path <path> -ContentDatabase <db> -Force -Confirm

Restore-SPSite : The site collection could not be restored. If this problem persists, please make sure the content databases are available and have sufficient free
 space.
At line:1 char:15
+ Restore-SPSite <<<<  http://qa.apps.blue.kraton.org/plm/sw -Path C:\Users\safarina\Documents\SemiWorksPLM11092014.bak -ContentDatabase QA_SPAppsSW_20140906 -Forc
e -Confirm
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreSite:SPCmdletRestoreSite) [Restore-SPSite], SPException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreSite
```

But this command works on other previously unused URLs.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

This is because OLD site still exist in the Content Database and become orphan. Basically when you run the Restore-SPSite command if the site already exist then it will delete 1st then restore it.

If you remember once you delete a site collection, it will go Central Admin Recycle Bin(access via powershell) and once it removed from their then you will able to restore again.

Here are solutions:

- Simple and easy, Create a Content Database then restore the site collection in that DB.
- If you dont want to create new content DB then follow instruction below.
  ee
- Run  `Get-SPDeletedSite` and you will see the name of site collection
  here
- Now get the ID of site and run `Remove-SpDeletedSite "Site GUID"`
- Final thing, browse **Central Admin > Monitoring > Job Definitions** and
  select the **Web Applicatio**n where you are trying to restore and run
  the **Gradual Site Delete**

http://wscheema.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=02e7c960-f007-4d7a-8bcf-94ec865f370e&ID=19&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fwscheema%2Ecom%2Fblog%2FLists%2FPosts%2FAllPosts%2Easpx&ContentTypeId=0x0110000CE6E96CD858F0419111D3D9045E5621

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I tried this and still get the same error.  Get-SPDeletedSite doesn't show the old site at all.  Yet I still get the same error when trying to restore.  Any other ideas?

Comment: did you run the timer job which i mentioned in my reply

Comment: Yes, a few times, just to be sure.

Comment: try to detach the Content Database and wait for a min and then re attach it, after that try to restore. Chances are there are orphan stuff in the content DB....but on other hand you can simply create another content db and restore the site their.

Comment: I did this as part of the process.  I am able to restore the content DB, but only when using a different URL.  This basically kills the ability to do site restoration because each one kills a URL.  Is there really no way around this?

Comment: what command you using when restore with the same url....did you use content database parameter in your command?

Comment: The command from original post.  Yes included content database in it.  Different copy of DB doesn't work either.

Comment: how big the site collection is?

Comment: the backup is 140 mb